# Google Drive Editor Share button is disabled when viewed in an iFrame

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

We've developed an integration to our application where we wrap the Google Document Editor in an iFrame so that we can edit content in context of our application.  This week we've noticed that the Share button is disabled when working with Documents and Spreadsheets wrapped in the iFrame. (The Share button appears to work as normal with Presentations.)  Was there an update to the document editor that would cause the share button in the edit view to be disabled when viewed through an iFrame?  Is this a bug, or was this an intentional change?

Comment: This is a know bug, we're looking into the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing button is disabled by intention due to security reasons and will not be available for iframe embeds anymore.

Comment: Care to go into more detail?

Comment: It was a security concern not to allow to embedded frame to highjack the access token probably.

Comment: Hey - does Google have the concept of whitelisting? If so, would I be able to potentially get my domain on the whitelist? And if so, would that enable this button?